# Index IN and a range

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, innodb

I need to find the best index for this query:

```
SELECT c.id id, type
FROM Content c USE INDEX (type_proc_last_cat)
LEFT JOIN Battles b ON c.id = b.id
WHERE type = 1
    AND processing_status = 1
    AND category IN (13, 19)
    AND status = 4
ORDER BY last_change DESC
LIMIT 100";
```

The tables look like this:

```
mysql> describe Content;
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| type              | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| category          | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| processing_status | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| last_change       | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> show indexes from Content;
+---------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name            | Seq_in_index | Column_name       | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+---------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Content |          0 | PRIMARY             |            1 | id                | A         |        4115 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| Content |          1 | type_proc_last_cat  |            1 | type              | A         |           4 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| Content |          1 | type_proc_last_cat  |            2 | processing_status | A         |          20 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| Content |          1 | type_proc_last_cat  |            3 | last_change       | A         |        4115 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| Content |          1 | type_proc_last_cat  |            4 | category          | A         |        4115 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+---------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+


mysql> describe Battles;
+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                  | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| status              | tinyint(4) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| status_last_changed | int(11) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> show indexes from Battles;
+---------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name  | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+---------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Battles |          0 | PRIMARY   |            1 | id          | A         |        1215 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| Battles |          0 | id_status |            1 | id          | A         |        1215 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| Battles |          0 | id_status |            2 | status      | A         |        1215 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+---------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

And I get output like this:

```
mysql> explain
    -> SELECT c.id id, type
    -> FROM Content c USE INDEX (type_proc_last_cat)
    -> LEFT JOIN Battles b USE INDEX (id_status) ON c.id = b.id
    -> WHERE type = 1
    ->     AND processing_status = 1
    ->     AND category IN (13, 19)
    ->     AND status = 4
    -> ORDER BY last_change DESC
    -> LIMIT 100;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------------------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys      | key                | key_len | ref                   | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------------------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ref    | type_proc_last_cat | type_proc_last_cat | 2       | const,const           | 1352 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | eq_ref | id_status          | id_status          | 9       | wtm_master.c.id,const |    1 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------------------+------+--------------------------+
```

The trouble is the rows count for the Content table. It appears MySQL is unable to effectively use both last_change and category in the type_proc_last_cat index. If I switch the order of last_change and category, fewer rows are selected but it results in a filesort for the ORDER BY, meaning it pulls all the matching rows from the database. That is worse, since there are 100,000+ rows in both tables.

Tables are both InnoDB, so keep in mind that the PRIMARY key is appended to every other index. So the index the index type_proc_last_cat above behaves likes it's on (type, processing_status, last_change, category, id). I am aware I could change the PRIMARY key for Battles to (id, status) and drop the id_status index (and I may just do that).

Edit: Any value for type, category, processing_status, and status is less than 20% of the total values. last_change and status_last_change are unix timestamps.

Edit: If I use a different index with `category` and `last_change` in reverse order, I get this:

```
mysql> show indexes from Content;
+---------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name            | Seq_in_index | Column_name       | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+---------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Content |          0 | PRIMARY             |            1 | id                | A         |        4115 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| Content |          1 | type_proc_cat_last  |            1 | type              | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| Content |          1 | type_proc_cat_last  |            2 | processing_status | A         |          26 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| Content |          1 | type_proc_cat_last  |            3 | category          | A         |         228 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| Content |          1 | type_proc_cat_last  |            4 | last_change       | A         |        4115 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+---------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+


mysql> explain SELECT c.id id, type FROM Content c USE INDEX (type_proc_cat_last) LEFT JOIN Battles b 
USE INDEX (id_status) ON c.id = b.id WHERE type = 1     AND processing_status = 1     AND category IN (13, 19)     AND status = 4 ORDER BY last_change DESC LIMIT 100;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------------------+------+------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys      | key                | key_len | ref                   | rows | Extra                                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------------------+------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | range | type_proc_cat_last | type_proc_cat_last | 10      | NULL                  |  165 | Using where; Using index; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ref   | id_status          | id_status          | 9       | wtm_master.c.id,const |    1 | Using where; Using index                 |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-----------------------+------+------------------------------------------+
```

The filesort worries me as it tells me MySQL pulls all the matching rows first, before sorting. This will be a big problem when there are 100,000+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rows` field in `EXPLAIN` doesn't reflect the number of rows that actually were read. It reflects the number of rows that possible will be affected. Also it doesn't rely on `LIMIT`, because `LIMIT` is applied after the plan has been calculated.

So you don't need to worry about it.

Also I would suggest you to swap `last_change` and `category` in `type_proc_last_cat` so mysql can try to use the last index part (`last_change`) for sorting purposes.

Comment: So in that case, MySQL continues to pull rows in `last_change DESC` order until it finds `LIMIT 100` that match `category IN (13, 19)`?

Comment: @Mark Rose: yes. Mysql counts the expected amount of rows and stops execution. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/limit-optimization.html -- look at second item there.

Comment: I tried switching the order as you suggested, but I end up with a filesort. I've updated the question.

Comment: @Mark Rose: then change it back :-S It is a bit tricky to optimize order by in mysql